# не работает replayto formit

Tags: modx, formit

На почту письмо приходит, но не подставляется email отправителя. Если нажать "ответить на письмо" в почтовом клиенте,то письмо опять же приходит на мой ящик,а если убрать `emailFrom`, то письма с сайта не уходят.

```
[[!FormIt?
   &hooks=`email,redirect`
   &emailTpl=`MyEmailChunk`
   &emailTo=`ask@ru7lan.ru`
   &emailFrom=`ask@ru7lan.ru`
   &emailSubject=`Контакт! [[++site_url]]`
   &redirectTo=`6`
   &validate=`name:required,
   email:email:required,
   message:required:stripTags,
   number:required`
]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто:

```
&emailReplyTo=`[[+email]]`
```